# jquery slideToggle disrupts rest of layout

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

Created a main tester page.
http://www.danielamorescalchi.com/coreCorp/index.php#

The jquery function uses slideToggle to open/close the footer.
At the bottom right corner there is a button (orange w/star(for now)) so if the user clicks on it the footer comes up.
It works but it disrupts the rest of the layout.
How do I change this so the footer slides up w/out everything else moving?

I thought at first of changing the height of the core of the page (the wrap)and the position of the wrap's background image (no dice)
or giving the footer a dif z-index. (doubt it)

Can you folks advise on how to fix it or point me to a good tutorial?
Thx
D

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind if the footer is fixed to bottom of the window when the user clicks on it, which might be a good idea anyway since it only comes up when they want it.. All you have to do is add some css styling to the footer where it is like this

```
#footer { position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; }
```

using position: fixed should not disrupt the page layout other than the footer always being visible till they close the footer, go to a new page, or refresh the page. If you don't want to use fixed, you could also try the same thing just with position: absolute;

Comment: Thank you will give the absolute positioning and maybe the z-index a try. I actually want the footer to be invisible unless the user clicks on it.

Comment: Thank you will go try it out.
That seems the most likely solution. will go try it out and see how it works.